# Rails keeps changing its mind about which version of Ruby I have

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, gemfile

I am trying to put a website into production, but the system keeps changing its mind about which version of Ruby I have. First it complains that my ruby version is 2.4.1 and the version in my Gemfile is 2.3.3 so I go into the Gemfile and change it. Once changed it works fine to start with, then I run another command and it changes its mind and says the opposite (that the Ruby version 2.4.1 but I have 2.3.3 in my Gemfile)!!

[image: Magically changing Ruby versions]

What the hell?

Comment: You should use [RVM](https://rvm.io/)

Comment: I actually did use RVM.

Comment: RVM attempts to adjust itself to your Gemfile. Have you specified the ruby version there? It seems you have. RVM will tell you that you weren't using the same version and (hopefully) switch it for you... IIRC

Comment: I had the version 2.3.3 specified in the Gemfile. After I got the error message I changed it to 2.4.1. I changed it back to 2.3.3 when I got the second error but then when the server process starts it gives `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `require': incompatible library version - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/lib/bcrypt_ext.so (LoadError)`

Comment: Do you have a `.ruby-version` file? If so, what version does it specify?

Comment: Just a minute... I've tried `apt autoremove ruby`, but then it threw an error so I'm reinstalling 2.4.1 with RVM. Then if that doesn't I'm trying to the solution below. If it doesn't work I shall check...

Comment: `.ruby-version` = ruby-2.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Had to run `rvm remove 2.4.1` then do a new bundle install.

It's giving a whole host of new errors now, but they don't appear to be related to the the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this `rvm --ruby-version use 2.3.3`? Maybe your global ruby version is overriding whatever you have set for the project

Comment: I'll give it a go

Comment: Cool, if that solves it, I would also add a `.ruby_version` file, (from RVM) `echo 2.3.3 > .ruby-version`

Comment: Will I need to be in a particular directory to run that? I guess I can just run a find on `.ruby_version`? I assume there will only be one file called that?

Comment: Just the root of your project directory, did that work for you?

Comment: It's still doing the RVM reinstall. I really need to add at least a second cpu core to my remote server :/

Comment: Tried it. It's just giving me an incompatible library error: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/[...]` again.

Comment: Glad you figured it out man, I've been there before, best of luck